# Duplicated item after consulting a View page in angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an `angular2` page that shows off some orders (for restaurants), those orders could be filtered by types (cancelled, in progress,... etc) within checkboxes, By default I'm loading the `open` and the `in progress` ones (they are checked by default when refreshing the page): 
[image]

The problem is that if I have **only one open** order, **if refreshing the page, it will duplicate that order (or in progress), when unchecking and checking any checkbox it will disappear and all stuffs are working smoothly**, I couldnt figure out what is the problem.
That is the relevant TS:

The relevant HMTL :

```
<div class="show-orders">
  <md-checkbox [checked]="true" (click)="showOpenOrders(isOpen)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'open' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox [checked]="true" (click)="showInProgOrders(isInProg)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'in_progress' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox (click)="showCompletedOrders(isCompleted)">{{completedStatus}}
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'completed' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox (click)="showCancelledOrders(isCancelled)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'cancelled' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  <md-checkbox (click)="showPaidOrders(isPaid)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'paid' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
</div>
<app-show-more
  *ngIf="!isOrdersLastPage"
  [label]="'showMoreOrders'"
  (getNextPage)="showMoreOrders($event)"
></app-show-more>
```

The relevant TS:

```
export class OrdersListComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() result: Order[];

  public totalOrders:      number;
  public isOrdersLastPage: boolean;
  public isCompleted:      boolean = false;
  public isOpen:           boolean = false;
  public isInProg:         boolean = false;
  public isCancelled:      boolean = false;
  public isPaid:           boolean = false;
  public status:           string[];

  private selectedName: string;
  private addOption(option: string) {
   this.status.push(option);
  }
  private removeOption(option: string) {
   this.status = this.status.filter(_option => _option !== option);
  }

  constructor(
    private router: UIRouter,
    private pageService:  PageService,
    private orderService: OrderService,
    private coreDataService: CoreDataService,

) {
    this.status = ['open', 'in_progress'];
    this.pageService.getPage().subscribe(
      (data: any): void => this.showMoreOrders(),
      (error: any): void => console.log(`could not load page data from orders home page`, error)
    );
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getOrders();
  }

  showMoreOrders(pageNumber = 0): void {
    let handleLoadOrders, handleLoadOrdersError;
    handleLoadOrdersError = (error: any): void => console.log(`coudn't load more orders`, error);
    handleLoadOrders      = (data: any): void  => {
      this.result           = this.result.concat(data.result);
      this.isOrdersLastPage = data.is_last;
    };
    this.orderService.loadOrders(this.status, pageNumber, this.isPaid).subscribe(
      handleLoadOrders,
      handleLoadOrdersError
    );
  }

  getOrders (): void {
    this.orderService.loadOrders(this.status, 0, this.isPaid).subscribe(
      (data: any): void  => {
      this.result           = data.result;
      this.isOrdersLastPage = data.is_last;
      },
      (error: any): void => console.log(`coudn't load more orders`, error)
    );
  }

  showOpenOrders(isOpen: boolean) {
    if (isOpen) {
      this.addOption('open');
    } else {
      this.removeOption('open');
    }
    this.getOrders();
    this.isOpen = !isOpen;
  }

  showInProgOrders(isInProg: boolean) {
    if (isInProg) {
      this.addOption('in_progress');
    } else {
      this.removeOption('in_progress');
    }
    this.getOrders();
    this.isInProg = !isInProg;
  }

  showCompletedOrders(isCompleted: boolean) {
    if (!isCompleted) {
     this.addOption('completed');
    } else {
      this.removeOption('completed');
    }
    this.getOrders();
    this.isCompleted = !isCompleted;
  }

  showCancelledOrders(isCancelled: boolean) {
    if (!isCancelled) {
     this.addOption('cancelled');
    } else {
      this.removeOption('cancelled');
    }
    this.getOrders();
    this.isCancelled = !isCancelled;
  }

   showPaidOrders(isPaid: boolean) {
    if (!isPaid) {
      this.isPaid = true;
    } else {
      this.isPaid = false;
    }
    this.getOrders();
    this.isPaid = !isPaid;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please also paste the relevant part of the template?

Comment: Done and thank you:)

Comment: please remove the white space charaters -`&nbsp;` - for simlicity of reading the code. Thanks :)

Comment: Done welcome :)

Comment: Thanks, but still know nothing. What I was asking for was the view where you present the orders (where it's doubled). In this case it's a template of component that implements the `app-no-content` selector.

Comment: @Baumi it is updated now

Comment: Sorry, still cannot see the template of `app-no-content`...

Comment: app-no-content is another different thing you can ignore it .. it is when there is no data it will be appeared .. it is not the issue now i think

Comment: My mistake... I didn't mean `app-no-content`. I ment template where the orders are displayed...

Comment: it is within the app-show-more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your problem in 2 requests that you execute on:

1) ngAfterContentInit

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.getOrders();
}
```

2) constructor

```
this.pageService.getPage().subscribe(
    (data: any): void => this.showMoreOrders(),
    (error: any): void => console.log(`could not load page data from orders home page`, error)
);
```

As in fact you make exact same request twice... Also `result` is defined as `@Input()`, so make sure that nothing above doesn't set anything there.

Comment: Comment one of those 2 requests (e.g. in constructor) and test it?